# Minified JSON in flask's jsonify()

Tags: python, json, flask, minify

Flask offers the convenient `jsonify()` function, which returns a JSON object from Python variables:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def json_hello():
    return jsonify({x:x*x for x in range(5)}), 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Which returns:

```
{
  "0": 0, 
  "1": 1, 
  "2": 4, 
  "3": 9, 
  "4": 16
}
```

(PS - note the conversion from int to string to comply with JSON).

This indented format is wasteful for long outputs, and I prefer the minified version:

```
{"1": 1, "0": 0, "3": 9, "2": 4, "4": 16}
```

**How can I get the JSON in minified version from Flask's `jsonify()`?**

Comment: Just use [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) from the standard library? (Though that's not not, strictly speaking, *minified*, just not pretty printed).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply set the configuration key [`JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR) to `False` - Flask pretty-prints JSON unless it is requested by an AJAX request (by default).

Comment: While this helps, removing indentation etc, it still includes unnecessary whitespace, for example: `[1, 5, 3]` instead of `[1,5,3]`.

Answer (score 19):

In addition to the other answer of `JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR`, you can also get rid of the spaces between list elements by extending flask's jsonencoder, like so:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.json import JSONEncoder

class MiniJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    """Minify JSON output."""
    item_separator = ','
    key_separator = ':'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.json_encoder = MiniJSONEncoder
app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] = False
```

The default values for `item_separator` and `key_separator` have a trailing space each, so by overriding them like this, you remove those spaces from the output.

(strictly speaking I suppose you could just set those values on the default `JSONEncoder` but I needed this approach since I had to overload `JSONEncoder.default()` for other reasons anyway)

Comment: Not sure if this is for an old version - but this is not needed as of current flask version. From flask doc (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/): This function’s response will be pretty printed if it was not requested with X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest to simplify debugging unless the JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR config parameter is set to false. Compressed (not pretty) formatting **currently means no indents and no spaces after separators**.

Answer (score 3):

Flask 1.1 will add indents and spaces to the jsonify() output if `current_app.config["JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR"]` is `True` (`False` by default) or the app is in debug mode.

From flask's source code:

```
indent = None
separators = (",", ":")

if current_app.config["JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR"] or current_app.debug:
    indent = 2
    separators = (", ", ": ")
```