# remove whitespace from JSON response by flask-restplus

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

How can you get rid of whitespace in the JSON response by flask-restplus routes?

[In a similar question, but for flask-restful instead of flask-restplus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25773493/755934), the answer suggested setting the config option `JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR = False`. This does not seem to work for flask-restplus.

I can't find anything in the documentation for flask-restplus around this either. What's the right way to do this? Anything better than overwriting the response handler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Glancing at the [source](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/blob/6c0b2897fa04b4625647e487eddea50472d1de4e/flask_restplus/representations.py), flask-restplus takes it JSON dumps settings from a flask config variable called RESTPLUS_JSON.  But also from the source, it looks like it would only pretty-print when running in debug mode.

Here's an example of manually controlling it:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
app.config['RESTPLUS_JSON'] = {'indent':None, 'separators':(',',':')}

@api.route('/hello')
class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world', 'abc':'def'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: This is almost right, but doesn't get rid of the newline at the end of the response. What should you add to the response above to get rid of the trailing newline?

Comment: @BlackSheep -- If you look at the source, you can see that they're explicitly adding the newline based on this github issue https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/pull/1262.  The only way you'd be able to get around that is monkey-patch out that function.

Comment: Just to add the justification to this answer so other folks don't have to go looking: (from [CHANGES.rst](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/CHANGES.rst))
> "JSON responses are now terminated with a newline character, because it is a convention that UNIX text files end with a newline and some clients don't deal well when this newline is missing. See https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/1262 -- this came up originally as a part of https://github.com/kennethreitz/httpbin/issues/168"